# IE gives Certificate warning although my website is served over http

Tags: php, css, wordpress, ssl

I'm currently working on a website for a client, that is served over HTTP as it mostly contains static content. However, in some Windows Configurations Internet Explorer gives a warning, that my security certificate isn't valid.

The site is made with a custom WordPress theme. Could it be that some plugin is the culprit of this problem? All my javascript libraries and stylesheets are also loaded over HTTP. Or are there any other common mistakes that I could have made?

The website URL is http://wolfgang-augsten.at.

Comment: Does other browser do the same thing?

Comment: as far as i can tell not really.

Comment: What configurations of Windows? It's fine in the latest version of IE on machines running W7 and W8...

Comment: My client uses Windows 7 and IE 11, and he sees the error.

Comment: Do you changed recently IP address, DNS or removed cert?